# Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeUpdate()

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am converting my mongo class to mongoDB manage driver, When i  try to execute the update command i have got the following  error

```
Error:
---------------------------------
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeUpdate()

This is my code
--------------------------------
$where  = array('status'=>1);
$set = array('status'=>2)

$updateOptions = array("multi" => true);
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 100);

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$result = $manager->executeUpdate("mydb.collection", $where, $set, $updateOptions, $writeConcern);
```

Also I tried with $manager->executeBulkWrite

```
Here is the code
----------------------------

$where  = array('status'=>1);
$set = array('status'=>2)
$updateOptions = array("multi" => true);
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
$bulk->update($where,$set,['multiple' => true, 'upsert' => false]);
$result = $manager->executeBulkWrite($db.'.'.$collection, $bulk);

I am trying to execute  $manager->executeBulkWrite on two collections same time and i got the error below
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: BulkWrite objects may only be executed once and this instance has already been executed
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue, Or any other alternative for updating the records in MongoDB\Driver\Manager

Answer (score 1):

After research I got solution for

```
 I am trying to execute  $manager->executeBulkWrite on two collections same time and i got the error below
 Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: BulkWrite
```

objects may only be executed once and this instance has already been executed

Here is the answer

```
As i said before i used two update queries at once while calling a function with global variable $bulk
When we try to update the data using $manager->executeBulkWrite in a loop, We should not use the global variable for 
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
foreach($arr as $ar){
   $where  = array('status'=>1);
   $set = array('status'=>2)
   $updateOptions = array("multi" => true);
   $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite();
   $bulk->update($where,$set,['multiple' => true, 'upsert' => false]);
   $result = $manager->executeBulkWrite($db.'.'.$collection, $bulk);
}
```

We need initialize the  BulkWrite every time in loop